# How to change the Edit template to appear at last column in autogenerated gridview

Tags: gridview, webforms, itemtemplate

I have a gridview in that fields are generated at runtime using `AutoGenerateColumns="True".` Before that in the design I have added a column as ItemTemplate to have Edit and Delete Row buttons.

Now the edit template column comes as the first column in my grid and all the autogenerated columns next.

Can anyone tell me a way to make the Itemtemplate field column to come as the last column in my gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the gridview's smart tags you should be able to move the column left or right as you wish.